# Hadoop reducing data from mapper to combiner

Tags: java, hadoop

I have a text input file conataining an URL + an variable ammount of keywords. this would look something like:

1. **facebook.com social news friends**
2. **msn.com news mail**
3. **yahoo.com finance news**

i need this to be transformed to output such as:

1. **social facebook.com**
2. **news facebook.com msn.com yahoo.com**
3. **friends facebook.com**
4. **finance yahoo.com**

my mapper class looks like this:

```
public class KeywordsMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
private Text urlkey = new Text();
@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] line = value.toString().split(" ");
    ArrayList<String> keywords = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String sequence : line) {
        if (sequence.endsWith(".com")) {
            // url
            urlkey.set(sequence);
        } else {
            // keyword
            keywords.add(sequence);
        }
    }
    for (String keyword : keywords) {
        context.write(new Text(keyword), urlkey);
    }
}
}
```

my reducer / combiner class looks like this:

```
public class KeywordReducer extends Reducer<Text, Iterable<Text>, Text, Text> {
public void reduce(Text key,  Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String body = "";
    for(Text part : values){
        body = body + " " + part.toString() + " ";
    }
    context.write(key, new Text(body));
}
}
```

the job looks like this:

```
public class KeywordJob extends Configured implements Tool{

@Override
public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
    Job job = new Job(getConf());
    job.setJarByClass(getClass());
    job.setJobName(getClass().getSimpleName());

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(arg0[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(arg0[1]));

    job.setMapperClass(KeywordsMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(KeywordReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(KeywordReducer.class);


    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
}

public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
    int rc = ToolRunner.run(new KeywordJob(), args);
    System.exit(rc);

}

}
```

The output i currently get is:

[image: output]

with an input file of:

```
yahoo.com news sports finance email celebrity
amazon.com shoes books jeans
google.com news finance email search
microsoft.com operating-system productivity search
target.com shoes books jeans groceries
wegmans.com books groceries
facebook.com news social sports
linkedin.com news recruitment
```

The question: How would i need to adjust my combiner / reducer in order to get the desired output? Is there a specific reason why the output contains mutiple duplicate keys, and howcome they were not merged ?

Comment: Can you please be specific; I mean what is the problem. Even output is not showing up...! .. The output i currently get is:
<blank>

Comment: please read the first part of my question if you want to know what the problem is. I am running this on hadoop 2.3 as pseudo distributed system.

Comment: Rephrasing my comment - The output that the code is producing is NOT visible in the post.

Comment: @Anirudh actually it is. under the text "The output i currently get is:" followed by an image.

Comment: @MatthiasKricke hmm, could you clarify this a bit. The input file is space seperated. and in the reducer I would also add a " " space. i dont quite understand how the tabs are inserted. and could this actually be the reason why entries with the same key dont get combined?

Comment: @MarkStroeven sorry, mark i removed my commend. the tabs are inserted because they are the standard delimiter of key and value. Till now I can't see a problem in your code which confuses me... are you sure your reducer is called? it might be the identity reducer which writes this data. You used different styles in your code the map function is protected and overrides while the reduce function is public and did not override

Comment: @MatthiasKricke I changed the map and reduce functions to what they look like on the apache hadoop examples. (e.g. public void map and public void reduce). output remains the same though. The error lies within the fact that during the shuffle / sort phase duplicate keys are not merged it would seem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark,

The reducer is not being called/invoked.

The reducer class definition should look like -

```
public class KeywordReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>
```

instead of

```
public class KeywordReducer extends Reducer<Text, Iterable<Text>, Text, Text>
```

as the map output should correspond to this. The reduce() method signature is correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This whas the correct answer. Thank you very much for your help! is this a common rule that the output signature of a map should be identical to the input of a reducer?

Comment: Yes it is @MarkStroeven. Didn't you use an IDE? And didn't you get any error messages? This would have helped to see the mistake earlier.

Comment: Well yes, eclipse, but the hadoop build runs as pseudo distributed system. meaning that i have to export the jar / build with maven and run it through hadoop in my commandline terminal. I did not have any succes finding a suitable eclipse plugin.